# Use excel/sheets to do calculations in webapp with read/write to database?

Tags: javascript, php, excel, web-applications

Context:  I have several Excel spreadsheets that take user input, run a number of relatively complex and multiple step computations that rely heavily on excel's functions, and then output a summary table of results and graphs that are standard for my industry.  My clients have asked if I can turn this into a webapp, with all entry saved to a DB, and all results delivered in browser.  I know I could program it all in either php or javascript, but it would be difficult and very time consuming given how heavily I've relied on excel's functions.

Question: Is it possible for me to capture the data in forms, written in php, and saved to a sql database (or whatever language/db solution), and use those values to fill out the user input cells in my Excel spreadsheets, which will serve as the "calculation engine" in the background?

Preferences:  Prefer Php as I have significantly more experience than that than javascript.  Likewise, prefer SQL as DB solution.  Prefer Excel over Google Sheets, but can switch if needed.

Comment: Sure, you can use a library like this to edit spreadsheets https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Comment: @JimL, That looks like acool solution.  One question through, which I hope you can answer.  Let's say I have a pre-exiting spreadsheet that has a formula in cell A5 that is sum(A1:A4) and in A6 I have a formula that is (A5+1).  In PhpSpreadsheet can I read the spreadsheet in, write new values for A1:A4 and then pull A6 and display that to the user, or do I need to recreate the whole process?  

I guess what I am asking, in simpler terms, is if I have a series of calculations that are done in between the cells I write to and the cells I pull from, is that done automatically or do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're using Excel, I'm guessing you're running a Windows machine.  I know that you *can* treat Excel as a database using ODBC.   I'm not sure if making changes that way will trigger the recalculations you're looking for, but if it does, you can treat your Excel file as *a* database (but maybe not your final database).

If you were to move in this direction, there will be extra setup work to get Excel to run correctly if you're not logged in (alternatively, you'll need to configure your server so you're *always* logged in with Excel running).

For the long term, I would recommend looking at migrating away from using Excel to do your calculations.

Comment: Migrating away from excel is unfortunately not possible as my clients almost always want an excel spreadsheet (especially a final version once we've decided on all the inputs), which is why I was still hoping to run excel in the background... it ensures consistency, but having a DB that is outside excel will allow for better control of all the different cases that have been ran.

Comment: Ugh.  Well...it's what the client wants, and using Excel when Excel is the final product just makes sense.  If I'm understanding you correctly, the DB is simply to keep a history?  Any reason you couldn't just store the spreadsheets in the DB?

Comment: That's what we currently do... folder system with sheets named things like: "Project-A_Scenario_v57.3".  And not every scenario ends up being captured or something gets corrupted, etc.  On some of these projects we'll have 100s of spreadsheets.  What I'm hoping to achieve is to have a dropdown list in a website where I can select the correct scenario, pull it up, browse through outputs... and have all the INPUTS stored in a DB and have all the calculations done in a way that I know someone couldn't have accidentally screwed up by fixing a value in a cell that is supposed to be calc'd et.